# ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer funcionar angular-material?

Tags: layout, angular-material

Lo descargue del nuget pero al parecer no me funciona, ¿alguien podría darme consejos?,  ¿qué versiones de angular debo tener?

Tengo refereciadas todas en layout:

**referencias angular
angular-material.js
angular.min.js
angular-messages.js
angular-material.css
angular-aria.js**

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Te vas a tu proyecto y por medio del angular cli haces un npm install -s @angular/material @angular/cdk.
Después tienes que importar el módulo de angular material que quieras ocupar por ejemplo si quieres trabajar con los botones en el app.module escribes.
import {MatButtonModule} from'@angular/material/button';
Y lo pones en tus imports.
Recuerda que algunos módulos de material requieren de tener instalado las animaciones así que también instala las animaciones
npm install --save @angular/animations
Y en el app module importa el browserAnimationsModule .
Para más información visita la documen

Comment: pero es para implementar angularjs, creo que la version que me mandas en con agular2 para arriba